# Regex for route matching in PHP

Tags: php, regex, symfony, url

I am working on my mini url router in PHP. So far I've got regex for extracting variables in the url enclosed in {}(By looking at Symfony's router code) :

```
public function parse($pattern)
{
    $matches = '';
    $variables = array();
    $pos = 0;

    preg_match_all('#\{\w+\}#', $pattern, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_SET_ORDER);

    foreach ($matches as $match) 
    {
        $varName = substr($match[0][0], 1, -1);

        if(is_numeric($varName)) {
            throw new Exception('Argument cannot be a number');
        }

        if (in_array($varName, $variables)) {
            throw new \LogicException(sprintf('More then one occurrence of variable name "%s".', $varName));
        }

        $variables[] = $varName;
    }

    return ['variables' => $variables];
}
```

So this method extracts the vars, now I need a regex to match the pattern of the route with the url. I started learning about regexes, but I still am not that good to wrap my head around this.

Comment: So you need to know how this function works? Or you want another set of regex to do what you want? Don't quite get you :)

Comment: I need another regex :) I need to generate a regex so I can use it for matching, so if I have : /hello/{name}, the method so far only extracts 'name', but I need to generate a regex that will match /hello/Sam, I hope I am being clear in my question

Comment: You need to provide sample URLs. Also remove the router tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work: `\/hello\/{?([^\/}]+)}?`

(At least it does on the examples you provided:)

`/hello/{name}
/hello/Sam`

## Explanation

- `\/` is an escaped `/`
- `hello` finds `hello`, in case you didn't realize.
- `{?` finds a `{`, if there is one.
- `([^\/}]+)` finds everything that's not a `/` or `}`
- `}?`  finds a `}`, if there is one.

Comment: Great it works, but It would need to generate a regex against a given pattern. Depending on what the route path looks like. So if the route path is /users/{user_id/posts, it would need to generate something that matches /users/5/posts where 5 doesn't have to be limited to a number. Also if a another route path is /articles/old/{article_id/ it should generate regex that would match /articles/old/50

Comment: I think I got the hang of it, using your answer, the regex for /users/{user}/posts/{post} (route) users/Sam/posts/5 (url) would be \/users\/\{?([^\/}]+)}?\/posts\/{?([^\/}]+)}? and I need to use the programming language to calculate the regex

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might be interested, I got it, thanks to Laurel's answer.

This is the updated version of the method it still needs some work though :

```
$matches = '';
    $variables = array();
    $pos = 0;
    $reg = '#';
    $nextText = '';

    preg_match_all('#\{\w+\}#', $pattern, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_SET_ORDER);

    foreach ($matches as $match) 
    {
        $varName = substr($match[0][0], 1, -1);
        $precedingText = substr($pattern, $pos, $match[0][1] - $pos);
        $pos = $match[0][1] + strlen($match[0][0]);
        $nxt = $pos - strlen($pattern);
        if($nxt == 0) $nxt = strlen($pattern); 
        $nextText = substr($pattern, $nxt);
        //$precedingText = substr($precedingText, 1, -1);
        $precSegments = explode('/', $precedingText);
        $precSegments = array_splice($precSegments, 1);
        //$temp = 5; 
        echo 'nxt ' . $nextText . '<><br>'; 
        if(strlen($precedingText) > 1)
        {       
            foreach($precSegments as $key => $value)
            {   
                $reg .= '\/';
                $reg .= $value; 
            }

            $reg .= '{?([^\/}]+)}?';  
        }
        else
        {
            $reg .= '{?([^\/}]+)}?';
        }

        $nextText = str_replace('/', '\/', $nextText);

        if(is_numeric($varName)) {
            throw new Exception('Argument cannot be a number');
        }

        if (in_array($varName, $variables)) {
            throw new \LogicException(sprintf('More then one occurrence of variable name "%s".', $varName));
        }

        $variables[] = $varName;    
    }

    if(count($matches) < 1)
    {
        $reg .= str_replace('/', '\/', $pattern);
    }

    $reg = $reg . $nextText;
    $reg .= '#';

    if($pattern == '/')
    {
        $reg = '#^[\/]+$#';
    }

    return ['variables' => $variables, 'regex' => $reg];
```